# PHP + MySQL - Randomly list all the data from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, list, random

I got a table named clients in MySql. I want to list all the data from that table randomly in a php webpage. Is it possible to random the data whenever user visit the php webpage?

Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND();
```

This is mentioned in an example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). *As mentioned in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), `rand()` doesn't generate perfectly random numbers/sequence (but it will probably suffice for practical use on a website).*

You could also use `limit` to select only N (e.g. 5) records:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use it in my code. It's working but after I click to next page, some of the data in page 1 appear in page 2 and so on. I tried to edit my php code but it's not working. Do I need to use php coding instead of ORDER BY Rand()? Thanks :D

Comment: @user1822825 Yes, each time the query is run (it will be run each time you load the PHP-script, which will happen on "next page" etc), things will be randomized all over. If you want to avoid this, I think you're better off doing the randomization in PHP rather than the query. Some logic will be needed to avoid re-randomization between pages. I think that will be a question for another post, where you clarify and specify your needs...

Answer (score 2):

Add an `ORDER BY RAND()` clause to your query.

One warning though, this sorting will not be very efficient...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM clients
ORDER BY RAND()
```